# Разница между @singledispatch и @overload

Tags: python, python-3.x

В чём разница между [`@singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) и [`@overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)? С помощью чего в питоне делать переопределение?

Comment: @insolor `typing` и `functools` стандартные модули питона

Comment: @insolor имеется в виду overriding, а не overloading в классах, хотя декоратор `typing.overload` называется

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- `@overload` только декларирует (для линтеров или IDE) разные возможные сочетания аннотаций типов для **одной функции**
- `@singledispatch` выполняет переключение на нужную реализацию функции в зависимости от фактических типов аргументов

---

Наиболее краткое и понятное описание декоратора `overload` нашел [в его докстринге](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3240bc62f4e0afa09964f3afc845697f0a0806b9/Lib/typing.py#L1960):

```
def overload(func):
    """Decorator for overloaded functions/methods.
    In a stub file, place two or more stub definitions for the same
    function in a row, each decorated with @overload.  For example:
      @overload
      def utf8(value: None) -> None: ...
      @overload
      def utf8(value: bytes) -> bytes: ...
      @overload
      def utf8(value: str) -> bytes: ...
    In a non-stub file (i.e. a regular .py file), do the same but
    follow it with an implementation.  The implementation should *not*
    be decorated with @overload.  For example:
      @overload
      def utf8(value: None) -> None: ...
      @overload
      def utf8(value: bytes) -> bytes: ...
      @overload
      def utf8(value: str) -> bytes: ...
      def utf8(value):
          # implementation goes here
    """
    return _overload_dummy
```

Смысл такой:

##### 1. Если используется в стаб-файле (pyi)

Для одной и той же функции можно указать, что она может принимать разные типы аргументов. Т.е. реализация одна, а деклараций несколько:

Файл pyi

```
@overload
def some_function(value: int) -> int: ...
@overload
def some_function(value: float) -> float: ...
@overload
def some_function(value: str) -> str: ...
```

В py файле:

```
def some_function(value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value + 1
    elif isinstance(value, float):
        return value * 2.0
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        return "Hello, " + value
    else:
        raise TypeError
```

##### 2. Если используется в py-файле

- аналогично, декларирует различные варианты типов, в самих декларациях не должно быть реализации, а у реализации не должно быть декоратора `@overload` (*"In a non-stub file (i.e. a regular .py file), do the same but follow it with an implementation.  The implementation should *not* be decorated with @overload."*).

Т.е. по сути в предыдущем примере просто все складываем в один файл:

```
@overload
def some_function(value: int) -> int: ...
@overload
def some_function(value: float) -> float: ...
@overload
def some_function(value: str) -> str: ...


def some_function(value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value + 1
    elif isinstance(value, float):
        return value * 2.0
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        return "Hello, " + value
    else:
        raise TypeError
```

Таким образом, `@overload` **только декларирует** разные возможные типы аргументов и возвращаемых значений одной функции, **но не выполняет переключение** между разными реализациями одной функции.

Это можно рассматривать как альтернативу `Union`, с помощью которого можно было бы типы описать так:

```
def some_function(value: Union[int, float, str]) -> Union[int, float, str]: ...
```

Но с такими аннотациями не видно, что при полученном `int` возвращается `int` и т.д., а только декларируется, что может быть принят любой из перечисленных типов, и вернуться также любой из них (в любых сочетаниях).

[Более реалистичный пример из PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading):

```
from typing import overload

class bytes:
    ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> int: ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, s: slice) -> bytes: ...
```

Т.е. метод `__getitem__` (обращение через квадратные скобки) у объекта `bytes` при передаче целого числа (индекса) вернет целое число, а при передаче слайса вернет набор байт.

---

`singledispatch` наоборот выполняет переключение на нужную реализацию в зависимости от типа аргумента:

```
from functools import singledispatch


@singledispatch
def some_function(value):
    raise TypeError


@some_function.register
def _(value: int):
    return value + 1


@some_function.register
def _(value: float):
    return value * 2.0


@some_function.register
def _(value: str):
    return "Hello, " + value


print(some_function(2))  # 3
print(some_function(2.0))  # 4.0
print(some_function("Insolor"))  # Hello, Insolor
```

---

На мой взгляд, более красиво (без подчеркиваний вместо имен функций) "переключение" между реализациями в зависимости от типа аргумента реализовано в библиотеке [fastcore](https://github.com/fastai/fastcore):

```
from fastcore.dispatch import typedispatch


@typedispatch
def some_function(value):
    raise TypeError


@typedispatch
def some_function(value: int):
    return value + 1


@typedispatch
def some_function(value: float):
    return value * 2.0


@typedispatch
def some_function(value: str):
    return "Hello, " + value


print(some_function(2))  # 3
print(some_function(2.0))  # 4.0
print(some_function("Insolor"))  # Hello, Insolor
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял из документации:

- `@singledispatch` используется, если у вас один обязательный аргумент, но разных типов
- `@overload` может использоваться для разных сочетаний количества и типов аргументов

Ну, примерно так. Детали там какие-то заумные, насколько я понял, это разные попытки создателей языка сделать механизм перегрузки функций.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload
в примере 1 аргумент

Answer (score 0):

В целом обе функции делают одно и то же, но разница заключается в том, как это работает под капотом.

#### typing.overload

Модуль typing версия за версией работает в сторону сближения динамически типизированного python и строго типизированного c++. Касательно работы:

- Типы аргументов для каждой перегрузки определяются строго
- Если нет точного совпадения- вызывается неперегруженная функция
- Нельзя напрямую вызвать декорированную функцию, только одноименную недекорированную
- Результат работы декоратора - `typing._overload_dummy`

  ```
  inp [1]
  from typing import overload
  print(overload(sum))
  ```

  ```
  out [1]
  <function typing._overload_dummy(*args, **kwds)>
  ```

#### functools.singledispatch

Модуль functools работает в рамках языка python (не ручаюсь что целиком и полностью) и пользуется тем, что функции - это тоже объекты и у них есть масса собственных интересных свойств (почитайте например про замыкания).
Касательно работы:

- Из всех декорированных функций с **одним** аргументом ищет наилучшее совпадение
- Можно вызывать перегруженные функции
- Результат работы - `<function __main__.sum(a, b)>`

  ```
  inp [2]
  from functools import singledispatch
  print(singledispatch(sum)
  ```

  ```
  out [2]
  <function __main__.sum(a, b)>
  ```